# How to keep sensitive data in browser cache?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I have an app with a loggin system. When the user is logged-in, he receives an http-only cookie with is id, and a json that contains all his information but his password. His infos are stored in a global state. So far so good.

The issue is that each time I refresh the page or open a new tab, the user is logged-out, because the state becomes empty, and the api call to retrieve the user-informations may not be fast enough.

The ideal would be to store the infos in a cache for 24 hours or so. But these infos may be sensitive: geolocation, etc. So I need a secure way to store them. Localstorage and indexedDB don't provide any security. I don't know what to do.

When I check my application tab in Reddit or other web app with a loggin system, I only see a simple token such as "isLogged: true". No infos, no profile picture url, etc. Yet, my profile is loaded instantly, profile picture and username included.

So I assume they use some processes I don't know about. How to cache sensitive data in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

It is normally **NOT** recommended to store sensitive user infomation on client side. However you can use an encryption library to encrypt and decrypt the stringified data if needed. You can try the [Standard Javascript Crypto Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sjcl)

```
const your_obj = {
  key: "value"
};
const key = "some_constant_key"
const stringified = JSON.stringify(your_obj);

const data = sjcl.encrypt(key, stringified);

localStorage.setItem("MY_DATA", data);

// retrieve the data
const encryptedData = localStorage.getItem("MY_DATA");
const decryped = JSON.parse(sjcl.decrypt(key,retrievedData))
```